# iterating through a list of JSON objects

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate through a list of JSON objects

but I get `"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"`.

```java
List<JSONObject> records;
        for(JSONObject record : records) {
      ....
      }
```

Comment: please post what you got so far so we can reproduce

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the objects you are trying to iterate are type of JSONObject and not String?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. I got the impression the problem is not in the snippet you provided.

Comment: @Cassendra44 yes it is JSONObject. If not I how would I add it to the list of JSONObject?

Comment: Welcome to SO, that will be really helpful to trace actual problem. But what I can assume your trying to do it putting String directly in JSON object, instead of putting it with proper key.